# Preview Multiple images on single page

Tags: javascript, html

This code over-writes the image for multiple input tags
and image preview is displaying at bottom of all tags
I tried a lot!

I want to preview Multiple images on single page.
Please tell me how to loop with this script.

```js
if (window.FileReader) {

  var reader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/cis-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x-cmu-raster|image\/x-cmx|image\/x-icon|image\/x-portable-anymap|image\/x-portable-bitmap|image\/x-portable-graymap|image\/x-portable-pixmap|image\/x-rgb|image\/x-xbitmap|image\/x-xpixmap|image\/x-xwindowdump)$/i;

  reader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    preview = document.getElementById("uploadPreview1")
    preview.src = oFREvent.target.result;
    preview.style.display = "block";
  };

  function doTest1() {

    if (document.getElementById("myfile1").files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    var file = document.getElementById("myfile1").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(file.type)) {
      alert("You must select a valid image file!");
      return;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  reader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    preview = document.getElementById("uploadPreview2")
    preview.src = oFREvent.target.result;
    preview.style.display = "block";
  };

  function doTest2() {

    if (document.getElementById("myfile2").files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    var file = document.getElementById("myfile2").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(file.type)) {
      alert("You must select a valid image file!");
      return;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

} else {
  alert("FileReader object not found :( \nTry using Chrome, Firefox or WebKit");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <p><input type="file" id="myfile1" name="myfile1" size="30" onchange="doTest1()"></p>
    <img id="uploadPreview1" src="" width="100" style="display:none" />
  </div>
  <br><br><br>

  <div>
    <p><input type="file" id="myfile2" name="myfile2" size="30" onchange="doTest2()"></p>
    <img id="uploadPreview2" src="" width="100" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `doTest(index)` and then `var file = document.getElementById("myfile"+index).files[0];` or pass the file object using `doTest(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hint: You are over-writing the reader.onload handler function. That's why the image is always displayed as src of uploadPreview2 img.